# When to use "ce qui" and "ce que" instead of "qui"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

I've been having trouble with differentiating when to use "ce qui", and "ce que" instead of "qui". Like here:

If you were translating "That's my reaction every time I see her, which is always" would you say

> C'est ma réaction chaque fois que je la vois, ce qui est toujours

Or

> C'est ma réaction chaque fois que je la vois, qui est toujours

And another:

If you were saying something like:

The reason why I like this tree rather than the other one is because, this tree has fruits which the the other tree doesn't have.

Would you say

> La raison pour laquelle j'aime cet arbre plutôt que l'autre c'est parce que cet arbre a des fruits, ce que n'a pas l'autre arbre

Or

> La raison pour laquelle j'aime cet arbre plutôt que l'autre c'est parce que cet arbre a des fruits qui n'a pas l'autre arbre

Sorry if my French is wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, to answer your question about these specific instances, the correct formulations would be :

> C'est ma réaction chaque fois que je la vois, **CE QUI** est toujours ...
>
> La raison pour laquelle j'aime cet arbre plutôt que l'autre c'est parce que cet arbre a des fruits, **CE QUE** n'a pas l'autre arbre.

To speak more generally, **ce que**/**ce qui** are used like **que**/**qui**, only when there is no expressed antecedent ; for example, they're used to refer to an idea. In your second example, the idea is "the ability to bear fruits".

Then the choice between using **que**/**ce que** or **qui**/**ce qui** will depend on the grammatical function they occupy in the sentence. **que** is used when serving as the direct object ; **qui** is used when serving as the subject.

In your second example, we're using **ce que** because the pronoun is the direct object. If we were to replace the pronoun, it would be as follows :

> L'arbre n'a pas [la faculté de produire des fruits]

These two links can provide you with more info if needed : [link](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/relativepronouns_2.htm) and [link](http://laits.utexas.edu/tex/gr/pror2.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: What I meant by the second sentence is: "This has fruits, which the tree doesn't have". I'm not referring to the kind of fruit the favoured tree contains, but fruits in general.

Comment: Like the meaning changes in English when you add a pause in between "fruits" and "which". In the sentence, "which" and "that" are not interchangeable

Comment: Hey, got it ; updated my answer to reflect this better. Does it make more sense ?

Comment: i'm trying to understand this answer. The first sentence, you say that there is no expressed antecedent. But isn't *"ma réaction chaque fois que je la vois"* the antecedent? That is, you could rewrite "ce qui est toujours" as "***ma réaction chaque fois que je la vois*** est toujours", and thus it should be "qui est toujours"?