# Trouble parsing the grammar of this sentence with "ce que"

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, pronoms-relatifs

The [French subtitles](https://youtu.be/MXNnJIpb35M?t=7m34s) in this video are as follows:

> Et puis, ce que font aussi beaucoup de parents quand ils le peuvent, c'est ouvrir un livret pour mettre de côté un peu d'argent.

I have always only seen "ce que" followed by a subject and verb (altogether acting like some kind of object), and I have always only seen it be after a subject and verb. For example, "[Tu aime] [ce que j'ai]" -- [subject verb] [ce que subject verb ].

I was expecting "ce qui" instead of "ce que" in the above quotation. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the other answers are good. However, if I may hazard a third stab at it that capitalizes on your existing knowledge...

You say you already know that *ce que* can be followed by subject+verb, and when that's the case, it represents the object.

Well, the latter two elements of this structure often trade places.* So all you need to do is modify your rule slightly: *ce que* can also be followed by verb+subject, with the exact same meaning.

Hence, here it's *ce que* + *font* (verb) + *beaucoup de parents* (subject).

You might ask: Then how do I know that *ce que* represents the object, considering that *ce qui* is typically followed by verb+object in that order?

Answer: Because it's *ce que*, not *ce qui*, which safeguards it against this problem. :)

---

<sup>*For stylistic/euphonic reasons; compare with [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25885/que-followed-by-verbs/25886#25886).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The main clause in this sentence is "ouvrir un livret pour mettre de côté un peu d'argent" and the relative subordinate clause is "ce que font aussi beaucoup de parents (quand ils le peuvent)".

Emphasis is put on the subordinate clause by having it preceding the main clause. The use of "c' " is even more emphatic. This is quite a common construction.
*Ce que* and *ce qui* are used to refer to an idea instead of a specific noun (in which case *qui* and *que* would be used). If the  idea *ce que* is referring to was expressed just before the relative pronoun the sentence would be :

> Et puis, ouvrir  un livret pour mettre de côté un peu d'argent (c') est ce que font beaucoup de parents quand ils le peuvent.

The question on when to use *ce qui* and *ce que* has already been asked on French Language : [When to use "ce qui" and "ce que" instead of "qui"](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/19821/358). *Ce que* is used here because the relative pronoun acts as object in the subordinate clause (the subject is  *beaucoup de parents*).

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: It sounds like the sentence should switch "font" and "beaucoup de parents" to me, though: "Ouvrir un livret [...] est ce que beaucoup de parents font [...]". We say "My parents made cookies" ("Mes parents font des biscuits"), not "Made my parents cookies" ("Font mes parents des biscuits"). a) Am I right that "font" and "beaucoup de parents" are out of order? and b) If I'm right, why are they switched to be out of order like this?

Comment: (can't edit my previous comment, so here is new one). Luke's answer below answered my question I just asked, but your answer gave me my first step of understanding that I had needed, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

*Ce que* and not *ce qui* is correct here. You have to remember that *que* is used when the relative is the object of a verb, and *qui* when it is the subject. It is true that sentence starting with *Ce qu-* is more likely to use *ce qui*, but here the "unwound" sentence is:

> Ouvrir un livret pour mettre de côté un peu d'argent est ce que font aussi beaucoup de parents quand ils le peuvent.

Here the relative starting *ce qu-* is the object (well, technically the *[predicative expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression)* in this case, but the syntactic effect is the same), thus *que* as the relative pronoun.

Comment: (i still have to dedicate time to carefully read these replies). but i'm wondering if my poor understanding with the grammar concept of "causative faire" is part of what is giving me trouble here. (i'm only realising this now, from reading your "unwound" sentence)

Comment: @silph Yes, since you knew when to use *ce qui and *ce que* it was obvious you did not understand the sentence because of the way it was built, that's why I expanded on it that in my  [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/26565/358).

Comment: @silph If you though there was a causative here (there is not), then yeah, I can see how that would screw up with your attempts to understand the syntax.it's really just topicalization to move the element you want to focus on first in the sentence (i.e. [clefting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence#French) )